# How to Add an event to a list of button at runtime

Tags: c#, events, button

I am trying to create buttons at runtime. My Question is that How should I add an Event to each of the buttons at runtime mode also?

For example:

```
Button btn;
int i =0;
int j =0;
List<Button> listBTN = new List<Button>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(60 + i, 90);
        btn.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        btn.Name = "BTN";

        listBTN.Add(btn);

        i = i + 50;

        foreach(Button b in listBTN){
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Button[] {b});
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
btn.Click += yourMethod;

private void yourMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your implementation
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        //use btn
    }
}
```

if you want to add the event when you declare the button use:

```
btn.Click += delegate
{
     //your implementation
};
```

Comment: that's just adding a same event to all of the buttons. What I'm trying to figure out is how to put a unique event to each of the buttons.

Comment: The event handler method which is reused. The event instance is created with each instance of the button.

Comment: for that - give each button a unique name, and in the event handler use the btn.Name to know which is it, or use 'AnonymousMethods':
btn.Click += new delegate{//your implementation here'};

Comment: I think that's the solution. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "BTN" + i.ToString(); //just to be sure you can distinguish between them
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

And add default handler for all buttons:

```
    void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        MessageBox.Show("You have clicked button number " + btn.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Yes yes, I think you got my point. I also tried that solution a while ago. But What I want is that every time I add a button I'm also adding an event to that button. Is that possible?